# configure Xuggler on Ubuntu 14-04

Tags: java, ubuntu, ant, ffmpeg, xuggler

I was trying to install Xuggle on Ubuntu with [this tutorial](http://www.lengrand.fr/2014/07/compiling-xuggle-on-ubuntu-14-04/)

But when I used `ant stage` it doesn`t work. I see these commands on the terminal

```
> root@test1:~# ant stage Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find
> it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar Buildfile:
> build.xml does not exist! Build failed
```

Do you have any idea how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tools.jar error will be because ant can't find your JDK, it appears to be looking in the open JDK location. You might need to install oracle-java7-set-default so it points your system java to the oracle java you just installed.

Comment: I fixed Oracle java7. When I use "$ ant stage" in command line, it works and installed some packages but at the end I still see this command :
"

Comment: [exec] cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
     [exec] make[6]: *** [Codec.lo] Error 1
     [exec] make[5]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
     [exec] make[4]: *** [all] Error 2
     [exec] make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
     [exec] make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
     [exec] make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
     [exec] make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

BUILD FAILED
/root/xuggle-xuggler/mk/buildtools/buildhelper.xml:1192: exec returned: 2